# Map throw error on duplicate insertion

Tags: java, dictionary

I am creating a Map with stores some data and i want the map to throw an exception if a duplicate value is tried to insert.

```
Map <Integer, String> temp;
temp.put(1, "hi");
temp.put(1, "hello");
```

Here this map should throw an error since a key '1' is already present. 
It can throw an error or does not compile. 
Is there any map which has said functionality?

Comment: the code above will always throw a NullPointerException, since you didn't even initialise your temp Map. duplicates or not.

Comment: There's no need for a Map to have such a functionality, since you can always call `if (temp.containsKey(1))` to avoid such an exception.

Comment: @Stultuske I know i did not initialize the map because i don't know with which implementation to implement it. It can be HashMap() or ImmutableMap or any other.

Comment: The `Map` interface defines the replacement behaviour of `put` - so any implementation that does something different would be in violation of that contract.

Comment: Also, to prevent having to check for duplicate value accross your application, I would suggest extending the HashMap class and overriding put method to check for duplicate and then only insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check containsKey method.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    map.put(1, "Value");
    if (map.containsKey(1)) {
        throw new Exception("Map already contains key 1");
    }
```

For your question, you can create your own implementation like:

```
public class MyCustomMap extends HashMap {

        @Override
        public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
            if (this.containsKey(key)) {
                System.out.println("Do whatevery you want when key exists.");
                return null;
            } else {
                return super.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Map<Integer, String> map = new MyCustomMap();

        map.put(1, "Value");

        map.put(1, "Another value");

    }
```

*Note: This is example, without null checking etc.*

**But please, always try to check JavaDoc or basic data structure use cases before asking here, I believe that on Google is a ton of examples ;)**

Comment: we can use only the second solution when the map is being used by external library. But problem is it also fails silently. Or, we can throw RuntimeException.

Answer (score 8):

Using a contains-check prior to the put-operation is not an atomic-operation and therefore not thread-safe. Additionally, the map has to be accessed twice each time you add an entry.

To avoid this, use one of the functional methods like merge or compute:

```
map.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate key '" + key + "'.");
});
```

Comment: This solution is limited to throwing instances of `RuntimeException`. A better solution would be one which can throw `Throwable` as it would force consumers to handle it.

Comment: @OSGIJava unfortunately yes. you can catch the runtime exception of the merge call and throw a checked exception.

Answer (score 1):

Map doesn't throw any error or exception while trying to add new value with a key that is present in the map. In that case old value is simply being replaced with a new value.

If you want to add a functionality that will throw an error in that situation, you can use

```
if(map.containsKey(yourKey)) // here your error action
```

Answer (score 0):

> Map.put returns  the previous value associated with key, or null if there was
>   no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports
>   null values.)

So you can do this:

```
public void addItem ( Integer key, String value ) throws Exception {
  String old = map.put( key, value );
  if ( old != null) {
     throw new Exception("Already exists!");
  }
}
```

Beware: in this code the new value is instered anyway, even though the key already existed, you cannot add null as it will throw an exception.

Comment: This is not a good solution. The map was modified before the exception was thrown. The OP wanted to prevent updating the map.